# Restoring a Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, site-template, recycle-bin

I accidentally deleted one of our Site Templates from our SharePoint Online tenant. I restored it from the Admin Recycle Bin but the site did not fully restore. The UX wasn't applied, and the lists and contents are missing. It looks like it restore a blank Project template and not the one that was deleted. I definitely restored the correct one because I looked at the time stamp and the URL was the same. Has anybody encountered this? How can I get my Site back and fully restored?

Comment: Might have to contact Microsoft Support.  Good luck--you'll need it, they're useless.

Comment: Yes, maybe but I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: did you delete the complete sites or just template?

Comment: I went to site settings and clicked Delete this site. The site collection was our project template being used for new project sites